# Promote Dashboard of Worksheets from DEV to upper ENV Snowflake/ Snowsight

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to promote changes on a Dashboard or Worksheet automatically in Snowflake from DEV to Stage or PORD, but have not found an option to do it

There was this library to import and export [sfsnowsightextensions](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/sfsnowsightextensions) but it stop working and doesn't look it will work any time soon

I am not sure if we can store the changes in a schema metadata to create dashboards automatically

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not currently possible